# How to use chrome.storage in a chrome extension using a variable's value as the key name?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to use chrome's local storage / sync storage (chrome.storage) for an extension, to store data entries, for many different entries.  I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for it.  I only want to simply store the information as strings.  I have searched and can't find anything yet that works.

This is what works for me at the moment using the normal localStorage technique:

```js
    var imageName = "Red Cat 5";
    var myDescription = "A nice kitty";

    localStorage.setItem (imageName, myDescription);
    console.log(localStorage[imageName]);
```

This works and lets me set the key from an existing variable.
How can I do it using chrome.storage.local.set?
I have been trying this without any success:

```js
    var imageName = "Red Cat 5";
    var myDescription = "A nice kitty";

    chrome.storage.local.set({imageName: myDescription}, function()
    {console.log('success?');});

    chrome.storage.local.set({imageName: myDescription}, function()
    {chrome.storage.local.get(imageName, function(r){console.log(r.imageName);});});
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

*----- UPDATE BELOW -----*

Thanks for the explanation with the code.  I hope it helps anyone else.  There seems to be little information available on doing this!  Your answer helped me come up with this:

```js
    var nameOne = "al";
    var nameTwo = "bob";
    var nameThree = "carl";
    var nameFour = "dan";

    var dataObj = {};

    dataObj[nameOne] = nameTwo;
    dataObj[nameThree] = nameFour;

    storage.set(dataObj);

    storage.get(dataObj, function(result)
    {
    console.log(result[nameOne]);
    console.log(result[nameThree]);
    });
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a named object, not an anonymous object, and set a member variable using square brackets:

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj[imageName] = myDescription;
chrome.storage.local.set(dataObj, function() { /*...*/ });
```

It's not the most elegant looking code, but it's the only way to do it.

In ES6, a slightly shorter approach is to use an object literal with a dynamic property name:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
    [imageName]: myDescription
}, function() { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this information. It makes it a bit easier to understand. With your help, I came up with something that seems like it will do what I need!  See above in the question for an example.

Comment: By the way...is it possible to use the three lines of code in your answer, without the function part, in one single command?

Comment: You could wrap it in a function like `setlocalData(keyNameString, value, callback)` which uses the three-line version I've posted. Other than that, not, I don't think so.

Comment: Out of interest, what's different about an anonymous object that it doesn't work?

Comment: @rich An object literal can only have literal property names. Here, we need a *variably* named property. Suppose you want a literally-named property called `bazzle`; you can do either `{bazzle:5}` or `o = {}; o["bazzle"] = 5;`. However, if you *don't know* the name of the property you want (i.e., it's stored in a variable), you can only do the second case `o[stringWithPropertyName] = 5;`. There's no way for an object literal to use a variable as a property name; namely, `{stringWithPropertyName:5}` will use the literal string to the left of the colon.

Comment: What does this function() do?

Comment: @onegrx The function is a callback that runs after the storage operation completes.

Comment: @apsillers, `exec` would give you a *variably* named property right?

Comment: @Pacerier I admit that "only way to do it" is a slight overstatement; it's really the only way to do it without dynamic code generation. `eval` is also an option in the same way that blasting off in a rocket and plummetting back to earth is technically one possible way to go to the grocery store. `:)`

Comment: JS is death by a thousand cuts. This detail tripped me up for several hours. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

the `set` method accepts **object items**, and an optional callback, the `get` accepts **optional string or array or object keys** and if you passed the first argument, you got to pass the second argument as well.

Example:

```
// To set 
chrome.storage.local.set({'testKey':'Test Value'});

// To get
chrome.storage.local.get('testKey', function(data){
  console.log(data); 
  // logs out "Object {testKey: "Test Value"}"
})
```