# Using a URL as a key in Chrome's local storage dictionary

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to store a list of some values in Chrome's local storage for use in a Chrome extension. Since each list correlates to a URL, I'm trying to use the URL as the key in the key-value store. However, for some reason `set()` appears to fail when using a URL as a key (even though `typeof(url_variable)` reveals that it's just a string) but if I use some contrived string such as `"hello"`, I'm able to retrieve the stored object normally.

Is there a restriction on using URLs as a key? There isn't any mention of it in the API.

It should be noted that Chrome isn't setting `runtime.lastError`, the lookup merely fails when I try to `get()` the key that was previously `set()` with a URL.

This is the code, for reference:

```
function addNode(url, referrer) {
  nodes = chrome.storage.local;
  edge = {
    in_node: referrer,
    timestamp: Date()
  };

  nodes.get(url, function(current_node){
    console.log(current_node);
    if ( $.isEmptyObject(current_node) === false ) {
      // never executes, because set doesn't work
    }
    else {
      console.log("set: "+url);
      nodes.set({url:[edge]}, function(){
        if ( chrome.runtime.lastError ) {
          console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        else {
          console.log("get: "+url);
          chrome.storage.local.get(url, function(thing) {console.log(thing)});
          console.log("Created new Node for url " + url + " and new edge from " + edge.in_node + " at time " + edge.timestamp);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Tested _sessionStorage_ interface with a uri, `sessionStorage.setItem('http://foo.bar/f.b', 'hello world'); sessionStorage.getItem('http://foo.bar/f.b'); // "hello world"` What are you trying to store?

Comment: I'm storing a list of 'edge' objects, which are basically just objects containing two strings... maybe those aren't serializing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating the object first like this [How to use chrome.storage in a chrome extension using a variable's value as the key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925770/how-to-use-chrome-storage-in-a-chrome-extension-using-a-variables-value-as-the)

Also maybe try except the exception instead of using an if block?