# Saving and loading data from chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I know there are a lot of similar questions and answers, but please, bear with me on this one.
I am not very skilled with Javascript and need help with 2 things.

I am working on a Chrome extension that extracts some data from web shop pages (product name, price, description...).

After I extract needed data I save it like this:

```js
var product = { image: "", name: "", description: "", price: "", url: "" };
product.image = "productImage";
product.name = "productName";
product.description = "productDescription";
product.price = "productPrice";

Save(product);

function Save(productValues) {
    productValues[document.URL] = productValues;
    chrome.storage.local.set(productValues, function() { /*...*/ });
}
```

After saving the data, I am trying to read it like this:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {
    console.log(items);}
```

This works fine, but Save() saves results like this (sorry for the image):

[image: Javascript result]

Basically, it saves objects properly, but also adds each parameter separately.

So my 2 questions are:

1. How to save a list of objects properly?
2. How to read the saved list back so I can iterate foreach saved object?

EDIT:

Expected result:

Expected result should be a list/array of all saved objects with URL as identificator/primary key (I followed [this advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925770/how-to-use-chrome-storage-in-a-chrome-extension-using-a-variables-value-as-the) ) which I could then iterate each object and generate HTML preview for each of them (something like C# foreach loop).

```
https://www.instar.hr/gopro-hero7...:
    description: "desc go pro"
    image: "https://..."
    name: "GoPro Hero 7"
    price: "3.156"
    url: "https://www.instar.hr/gopro-hero7..."
https://www.instar.hr/podloga-za-mis...:
    description: "desc podloga"
    image: "https://..."
    name: "Podloga za mis"
    price: "13,85"
    url: "https://www.instar.hr/podloga-za-mis..."
```

EDIT 2:
The code I am using:

```js
var product = { image: "", name: "", description: "", price: "", url: "" };
var productUrl;

function FindElements() {
    // get opened page domain
    var domain = window.location.hostname;

    var productImage;
    var productName;
    var productDescription;
    var productPrice;

    productUrl = document.URL;
    product.url = productUrl;

    if (domain === "www.instar-informatika.hr") {

        try {
            productImage = document.getElementsByClassName('productimage clearfix')[0].children[0].children[0].childNodes[0].currentSrc;
        } catch (error) {
            productImage = "";
        }

        try {
            productName = document.getElementsByClassName('productname clearfix')[0].innerText;
        } catch (error) {
            productName = "";
        }

        try {
            productDescription = document.getElementsByClassName('oblorub obloopis')[0].innerText;
        } catch (error) {
            productDescription = "";
        }

        try {
            productPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('productpageprice')[0].innerText;
        } catch (error) {
            productPrice = "";
        }

        product.image = productImage;
        product.name = productName;
        product.description = productDescription;
        product.price = productPrice;

        console.log(product);
        Save(product);
        Load();
    }

    else {
        window.alert("Sorry, current page currently not supported.")
    }
}

function Save(productValues) {
    var key = productValues[location.href];
    chrome.storage.local.set({[key]:productValues});
}

function Load() {
 chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {
  console.log(items);
  }
         
         
FindElements();
Load();

//After load, I need to do something like:
// foreach (product in items){
//    var htmlString =
//    "<h1>" + product.name + "</h1>" +
//    "<h1>" + product.description + "</h1>"
//    etc...
//    }
```

Comment: Can you edit and add expected results?
i'm not sure what are the proper keys and what are the unwanted in your example.

Comment: 1) remove "productValues[document.URL] = productValues;" 2) chrome.storage.local.set({[document.URL]: productValues}, ..............

Comment: exactly what i taught, his pointing only to the URL key.
but i'm not sure that's what he wants, in his example i'm seeing also "price", "name" and other keys that are not url outside an object.

Comment: @Anatsu I edited the question and added the result example. I hope it is clearer now. If not, please say, and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the help of @Anatsu I managed to solve my Save and Load functions like this:

```js
function Save(productValues) {
    var key = location.href;
    chrome.storage.local.set({[key]:productValues});
}

function Load() {
 chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {

  for (var key in items) {
   console.log(items[key].image);
   console.log(items[key].name);
   console.log(items[key].price);
      console.log(items[key].description);
  }

 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that storage will be a collection of objects where the URL is the main key?

```
function Save(productValues) {
 const key = productValues[URL]

 chrome.storage.local.set({[key]:productValues});
}
```

The product parameter below has to represent the object that you 
want to save in the chrome.storage

```
     Save(product);
```

Now enter the URL to get your object.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(yourUrl, function (items) {
 console.log(items);
};
```

But if you ask me, you better save it under "description" because I see it values is repetitive (Opis Artikla)

```
 function Save(productValues) {
  const key = productValues['description']

  chrome.storage.local.set({[key]:productValues});
}

chrome.storage.local.get('Opis Artikla', function (items) {
 console.log(items);
};
```

Comment: After I put "const key = productValues[document.URL]" it says that key is undefined: "key is undefined" so it just updates the same record everytime.

Comment: instead Document.URL try location.href .

Comment: It still says "key is undefined". URL is being read correctly, but the key won't get the value.

Comment: please `console.log(productValues)` in the top of `save()` function's scope and tell me what is printed.

Comment: i can't see the whole object,
maybe a link to codepen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195363/discussion-between-anatsu-and-matt).